# Derivative of an integral (Swapping integral and Differentiation)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $$F(t)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx} f(x) dx$$
f is an arbitrary probability density function

I want to compute $F'(t)$
Therefore I could use Lebesgue's theorem for swapping integral and differentiation.
I need a differentiable function that is an upper bound for the integrand. But how can I find such a function. I do not know anything about f?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be differentiable?

Comment: There is no further condition for f.

Comment: I'm assuming $t > 0$, else the integral doesn't seem to be well defined. Can't you use that the exponential is monotone, and so an upper bound for $F$ is $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$ then the fact that $f$ is a probability density function? I could be totally wrong though, its been a while since I learned this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $0<a<b<\infty$ and set $$u(t,x) := e^{-tx} f(x), \quad t \in [a,b], x \geq 0.$$ Then 
$u$ is differentiable with respect to $t$ and $$\partial_t u(t,x) =x e^{-tx} f(x).$$ In particular, $$|\partial_t u(t,x)| \leq x e^{-ax} f(x), \qquad t \in [a,b], x \geq 0.$$ Since the exponential function is growing faster than any polynomial, the function $[0,\infty] \ni x \mapsto xe^{-ax}$ is bounded, $$M := \sup_{x \geq 0} (x e^{-ax})<\infty.$$ Hence, $$|\partial_t u(t,x)| \leq M f(x), \qquad t \in [a,b], x \geq 0.$$ Since $f$ is a probability density function, the right-hand side is integrable. This integrable dominating function for the derivatives allows us to swap integration and differentiation: $$F'(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \partial_t u(t,x) \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} x e^{-tx} f(x) \, dx, \qquad t \in [a,b].$$ Since $0<a<b<\infty$ are arbitrary, this proves that $F$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $$F'(t) =\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-tx} f(x) \, dx, \qquad t>0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer;)